# Parse cmd line output seperated by spaces into grouped key-value pairs

Tags: python, regex, parsing

I get a command line output in the below format,

```
Name          Users           OS          Impact   Score    Comment Master Slave   Path 
INC03284      xyz7221         Windows       -     15/100      -       -      -       -
INC12739_1 abc1231 hfw4769 Windows Linux    -     36/100      -       -      -       -
Test_inc      xyz abc           Mac         1     152/200     -       -      -       -
os.ini.dark   sqwe326          Linux        1    1500/2000    -       -      -       -
safe_ini      zdh37251        Windows       -     0/3500      -       -      -       -
```

My desired output is a parsed comma separated grouped key-value pairs as displayed below,

```
Name="INC03284",Users="xyz7221",OS="Windows",Impact="-",Score="15/100",Comment="-",Master="-",Slave="-",Path="-"
Name="INC12739_1",Users="abc1231 hfw4769",OS="Windows Linux",Impact="-",Score="36/100",Master="-",Slave="-",Path="-"
Name="Test_inc",Users="xyz abc",OS="Mac",Impact="1",Score="152/200",Comment="-",Master="-",Slave="-",Path="-"
Name="os.ini.dark",Users="sqwe326",OS="Linux",Impact="1",Score="1500/2000",Comment="-",Master="-",Slave="-",Path="-"
Name="safe_ini",Users="zdh37251",OS="Windows",Impact="-",Score="0/3500",Comment="-",Master="-",Slave="-",Path="-"
```

Currently, I have been using **Python** to store the command line output into a string and have been trying to group the values into a regex as below,

```
^(?P<Name>[^ ]+)\s+(?P<Users>\w+)\s+(?P<OS>\w+)\s+(?P<Impact>\-)\s+(?P<Score>[^ ]+)\s+(?P<Comment>[^ ]+)\s+(?P<Master>[^ ]+)\s+(?P<Slaves>[^ ]+)\s+(?P<Path>[^ ]+)
```

However, my approach does not work in cases where there are multiple values which needs to be grouped together.E.g.`Users="xyz abc"`, `OS="Windows Linux"` and so on.

Would a single regex to extract all the information as required be the right way to proceed? How can I extract when the values need to combined in some cases as displayed in the example? Is there a different approach I can use here?

Comment: Create dict and use `line.split()` this should help.

Comment: @Tserenjamts, it will not ``abc1231 hfw4769`` will be splitted into two characters.

Comment: @Sushanth Yes you are right. And that is where I am stuck right now.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the values in OS all belong to a fixed list, for example ['Windows', 'Linux', 'Mac']. You could amend your user regex to match a space separated list of values which are not in that fixed list, so `(?:\w+)(?:\s+(?!(?:Linux|Mac|Windows))*`. Then for the OS column you can match a space separated list of these fixed values, so `(?:Linux|Mac|Windows)(\s+(?:Linux|Mac|Windows))*`.

Quoting from the documentation:

> `(?!...)`
>
> Matches if ... doesn’t match next. This is a negative lookahead assertion. For example, `Isaac (?!Asimov)` will match `'Isaac '` only if it’s not followed by `'Asimov'`.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. However, there are more in the list than ['Windows', 'Linux', 'Mac']. There can also be custom OS with custom names such as 'LinuxV16.04', Windows10' and so on.

Comment: Then you might want to change my regex to not test for this fixed list, but to check for something starting with an uppercase letter. If the only way to figure out what is an OS name and what is a user name is by manual inspection, then you could incorporate that into your script that you first do a guess, and then prompt "Is this correct? (y/n)" and enter the splitting point by hand if the guess is not correct.

Comment: The starting need not be an uppercase case well. Can be test_os, sample_win etc. This field contains known OS as well as custom OS created by users. The script needs to run in the background and send a parsed version into a database which relies on the output format that I specified.

Comment: Then I guess you're out of luck and will have to do things in a guess-confirm loop :(

Answer (score 0):

You need to be more precise with your groups. Here's a working expression for the data given:

```
^
    (?P<Name>[\w.]+)\s+
    (?P<Users>[a-z0-9 ]+[a-z0-9])\s+
    (?P<OS>[A-Z][A-Za-z ]+[a-z])\s+
    (?P<Impact>[-\d]+)\s+
    (?P<Score>[\d/]+)\s+
    (?P<Comment>-)\s+
    (?P<Master>-)\s+
    (?P<Slave>-)\s+
    (?P<Path>-)
$
```

You may need to specify what's allowed in `Comment`, `Master`, `Slave` and `Path`, respectively (actually, it's only `-`). See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/w11crb/1/) (and mind the modifiers).

Comment: Thank you. I guess my mistake was that I was trying to combine everything into a single regex. I would try this in my script.

Comment: I am stuck at certain parts of the regex, where the OS group is not properly extracted in some cases, as it need not always start in **Caps**. See **[regex link](https://regex101.com/r/w11crb/2)**. Here parts of OS gets extracted into the preceding group. I made slight modification in the User and OS groups to be more inclusive. However, been stuck here for quite sometime. Could you please guide.